# jCarouselLite bug when visible content is larger then item count

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousellite

I am using [jCrouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#what). if i set visible 3 and if there is only single element for slider so there is no anything appear. 
if you remove second element comment tag so both of them appear in the list.
You can try it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6uLj/1/)

Solution can be that setting visible count to element count but this is not what i am looking for.

It looks this is a bug. How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: You should provide your code.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you decrease the visible count if the number of image is one?

```
$('#carousel').jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".next",
    btnPrev: ".prev",
    visible: ($("#carousel li img").length>1)?3:2
});
```

Comment: I don't want this because changing visible count confuse users. If there is no enough content in slider i prefer to keep others empty.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#carousel { 
    border:1px 
    solid black;
    min-width: 0px !important;

}
```

this will force the carousel div to be at 0px when there is no picture in it and will grow as much as you need when adding pictures

http://jsfiddle.net/g6uLj/3/